# Override 5 finger Action in iOS Devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

We know that, there are many in-built gestures in iOS devices, one of them is we can go to Home screen using 5 Finger gesture.

I am just trying to override this action(method), to add some more features to my app, which is coded in `Objective-C`. I am trying to use UIGestureRecogniser for this, but no use.

Is it possible? (I am using 10.2,Xcode 8.2)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541530/over-ride-four-five-finger-pinch-gesture?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Multi finger is Not any gesture You can use as gesture as like this

```
  UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipeGesture:)];
  [swipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
  [swipe setDelaysTouchesBegan:YES];
  [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:swipe]


- (void) SwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
  NSUInteger touches = recognizer.numberOfTouches;
 switch (touches) {
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        break;
    case 3:
        break;
      case 4:
        break;
 case 5:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for tap gesture you could try:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(actionOnTap)];
gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 5;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;  // this prevents the gesture recognizers to 'block' touches
```

The most important is to decide which type of gesture you want to use(one of the following):

- UITapGestureRecognizer
- UIPinchGestureRecognizer
- UIRotationGestureRecognizer
- UISwipeGestureRecognizer
- UIPanGestureRecognizer
- UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer
- UILongPressGestureRecognizer

And the action you want to have after when that gesture happens.

IMPORTANT NOTE: The gesture recognizer has to be connected to UI Interaction Enabled element (e.g. UIView)

References: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizer